# Is it proper to use multiple 'greater-than / less-than' comparators in an evaluation?

Tags: c++, comparison

I was trying to see if a variable was within a range by using multiple `greater-than (>)`'s and `less-than (<)`'s in one evaluation. I was unsure whether this works or not though. It seems than [using multiple =='s is illigal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005485/how-to-overload-operator-to-allow-it-to-be-used-in-multiple-comparisons), but is it okay with < and >'s?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
if (bottomOfRange < variable < topOfRange) {
//Do stuff
}
```

I know that this:

```
if (bottomOfRange < varialbe && variable < topOfRange) {
//Do stuff
}
```

works, I'm just looking for an even more efficient way of comparing.

Will this evaluate how I want, or will it act differently?

Comment: A good answer has been given below. I'd just add that since the less-than operator is [left-associative](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `a < b < c` is evaluated as `(a < b) < c`. _Edit:_ I'm not sure how you could do "more efficient"...

Comment: yeah, Mike's bulleted section explains that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `bottomOfRange` and `topOfRange` are built-in types, then no, it won't accomplish anything useful.

If you want to badly enough, you could define a type that overloaded `operator<` to make it actually work though:

```
class range {
    int lower;
    int val;
    range(int lower, int val) : lower(lower), val(val) {}
public:
    bool operator < (int upper) {
        return lower < val && val < upper;
    }

    class start {
        int t;
    public:
        start(int t) : t(t) {}
        range operator < (int val) { return range(t, val); }
    };
};

#ifdef TEST

#include <iostream>

int main(){
    static char const *s [] = { "Out of range", "In range" };

    int variable = 20;
    range::start bottomOfRange(10);
    int topOfRange(30);

    if (bottomOfRange < variable < topOfRange)
        std::cout << "In range\n";
    else
        std::cout << "out of range\n";

    bottomOfRange = 30;
    topOfRange = 10;

    if (bottomOfRange < variable < topOfRange)
        std::cout << "In range\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Out of range\n";
}
#endif
```

Result:

```
In range
Out of range
```

Warning: this is intended primarily (purely?) as a curio. Although it obviously supports exactly what you've asked for, I'd be pretty hesitant about using it in my own code, and I'm not really recommending that you use it in yours either.

Comment: Interesting, I might have to look into this. For my purposes it's a little much, but it would be good to know for the future...

Comment: @TheWalkingCactus Take heed of Jerry's warning.  It's a clever trick, but the poor programmer who has to maintain the code is going to be very confused when he sees `if ( bottomOfRange < variable < topOfRange )`.  (For this sort of thing, it's better to define a class `Range`, and a member function `inBounds`, so the reader knows exactly what is going on.)

Comment: @JamesKanze good idea, thanks. I was already planning on making a class just for 'obscure' operations like that, but it's good to know that others have already succeeded in doing so.

Answer (score 8):

No. This code will probably compile, depending on the types of the variables, but won't give the comparison you want. It will:

- evaluate `bottomOfRange < variable` to give a boolean result;
- promote that result to a numeric type with value 0 or 1;
- compare that value with `topOfRange`.

If you want to compare a value against two other values, then you need to write out the two comparisons:

```
if (bottomOfRange < variable && variable < topOfRange)
```

Comment: And so because it treats true as 1 and false as 0, it would (almost) always evaluate to `true`?

Comment: @TheWalkingCactus: If `topOfRange` is greater than 1, yes.

Comment: alright, thanks. Sorry I can't accept your answer yet, still have a few more minutes to wait before I can.

Comment: Also, because this is such a simple answer, I think I can safely ignore [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post) because I doubt there is a more correct answer for something so simple

Comment: @TheWalkingCactus: Hmph. I post code that supports exactly what you ask for, and you have the nerve to say it's not a better answer. Ah, the cruelty. The inhumanity. The injustice! :-)

Comment: I stand corrected, there can be a more correct answer. Sorry @Jerry, I had simply not checked in the last 25 min, your answer IS better.